# How to push the two values "find" and "replace"

Tags: perl

```
my @storedContent = ();
my $string = "some content are stored....";

$string=~s/<whateverfind>/<whateverreplace>/gs && push @storedContent, $&;

print join "\n", @storedContent; #printing just <whateverfind>
```

I need to store the found and corresponding replaced strings in an array.

my expected output is:

```
<whateverfind>     <whateverreplace>
....
....
```

How can I do that?

Comment: It's a slightly analog solution, but is there any reason you can't just copy the text "<whateverreplace>" and put it into the `@storedContent` array? Any `$1`, etc references will get interpolated appropriately, just as they did in the replacement string.

Comment: It seems from your code that  `<whateverreplace>` is just a constant. Why do you need to put it in the array?

Comment: Also note thtat the `$&` in the `push` will only push the *last* value substituted by the previous `g` (global) substitution. All other substitutions will be discarded. Please clarify your question

Comment: @HåkonHægland: yes exactly I got only the last value. But I need whole replacing contents.

Comment: @ssr1012: Please don't add politeness like *please* to a question if the OP doesn't provide it themselves.

Comment: @Borodin: I will follow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`s///` returns the number of substitutions, so you could do this:

```
push @storedContent,
    ('<whateverfind>   <whateverreplace>') x $string =~ s/<whateverfind>/<whateverreplace>/g;
```

If you want to do it dynamically:

```
$string =~ s/<whateverfind>/
    my $r = "<whateverreplace>";
    push @storedContent, "$&   $r";
    $r
/eg;
```

Note that using `$&` entails a performance penalty on all regexes in your program in older perls, so you might want to use explicit captures instead:

```
$string =~ s/(<whateverfind>)/
    my $r = "<whateverreplace>";
    push @storedContent, "$1   $r";
    $r
/eg;
```